# Copying Google Docs documents with Java GWT

Tags: java, gwt, google-docs-api

According to the Google Documents List Data API there is an option to copy documents: 
http://code.google.com/apis/documents/docs/3.0/developers_guide_protocol.html#CopyingDocs

But when I look in the GWT Java docu of the API, this menu point is missing.
http://code.google.com/apis/documents/docs/3.0/developers_guide_java.html

Do you know, if there is a method to copy GDocs documents in the Java GWT API? Which maybe is just not documented?

Looking in the python API I find the python method:
http://code.google.com/apis/documents/docs/3.0/developers_guide_python.html#CopyingDocs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I now managed to write my own copy request:

Replace `t7Z3GLNuO641hOO737UH60Q` by the documents key, you like to copy

```
String = "new File";
String userEmail= new CurrentUser ().getUser ().getEmail ();

String body = "<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>"
      + "<entry xmlns=\"http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom\">"
      + "<id>t7Z3GLNuO641hOO737UH60Q</id>"
      + "<title>"+ title +"</title>"
      + "</entry>";

try {
  GDataRequest gdr = docsService.createRequest(Service.GDataRequest.RequestType.INSERT,
    new URL("https://docs.google.com/feeds/default/private/full/?xoauth_requestor_id="+ userEmail),
    ContentType.ATOM);

  gdr.setHeader("GData-Version", "3.0");
  OutputStream requestStream = gdr.getRequestStream();
  requestStream.write(body.getBytes());

  log.info(gdr.toString());
  gdr.execute();    
}
[.. catch]
```